# MySQL + Entity Framework + VPS Server

Tags: .net, mysql, database-connection

I have installed the MySQL Server on my VPS Server. Then, I want to use the Entity Framework in my app. I have downloaded the ADO.NET Connector.

I pass the server URL : http://IP_ADDRESS
and also the login & pass to the MySQL server instance.

[image]

When I test the connection, I get the error "`Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`" Why ?

### EDIT

SOLVED

I had to do 3 things:

1) add `bind-address=0.0.0.0` to the `my.ini` (MySQL config file)

2) `mysql> create user '___login___'@'%' identified by '___pswd___';`

3) `grant select, insert, delete on database_name.* to ___login___@'%' identified by '___pswd___';`

Comment: No server present at that location. Does it still use the default port number or has this been changed? Best to specify it in the connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, drop the `http://` part you should only provide the IP address here, nothing more.
Further there are 2 things you can check:

1) Does the MySQL server allow remote connections, Check the `bind-address` configuration in your `my.cnf`. This should be either unconfigured or the Public IP address of your VPS. I believe the default setting here is `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` which only allows local connections (you must restart the MySQL server after changing this)

2) Check if the 3306 port is being blocked by a firewall.

You can use Telnet to check if the MySQL server can be accessed remotely by using this command: `telnet <IP of server> 3306` If you can make a connection you should be able to connect remotely to your database as long as the user you are connecting as is allowed to make remote connections.

Comment: I can't see the my.conf file in the MySQL Server installation directory. Where it is ?

Comment: @Tony The standard location on Linux varies a bit but is most likely `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and I just realised that it's my.cnf not my.conf.

Comment: but the VPS server is running on the Windows Server 2008 R2. So, did You mean the my.ini file ? If so, inside it there is no 'bind-address' line

Comment: I used the telnet command and I get the error: Host 'SERVER_IP_ADDR' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: @Tony You are right, it is the my.ini file, I was assuming it was a Linux server. If the line is not present you can simply add it under the `[mysqld]` section

Comment: now I get the error while connecting from the Visual Studio: Access denied for user 'my_login'@'my_computer_ip' (using password: YES)

Comment: @Tony Considering the 'Host ... is not allowed to connect...' See this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html This means there is no User present in Mysql. For remote connections you need a User like <username>@% (allowed to log in from anywhere) or <username>@<host or public ip of your pc>.